# Ubuntu 20 DVD installs without asking, then won't boot (in VMware)

Tags: 20.04, vmware-workstation

I’m trying to evaluate Ubuntu live without installing, and to be safe I’m using a VMware virtual machine.  I downloaded the ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso image since I didn’t see any specific “live” image.  The first time I tried it I got the splash screen for a while, then left it alone while I did some other work, and when I came back it was just showing the Ubuntu logo on the bottom and not responding to any keys.  I rebooted the VM and while it was starting up I found I could switch between the splash screen and boot console by pressing Escape … at first, but after a while it stopped responding again.  Then I noticed that the virtual disk (.vmdk file) had grown to 5.5 GB, as if Ubuntu had been installed — I never saw the boot option menu asking me whether I wanted to “Try Ubuntu without installing” or “Install Ubuntu”.  So I went into the BIOS to ensure it booted from the DVD first and tried starting up again, this time making sure to stay on the boot console.

After going through the initial file checks it went back to the GUI, and this time instead of the splash screen it showed an “Install” dialog where it immediately began copying files.  After finishing that it went to “Installing system”, then “Retrieving file”, “Configuring hardware”, removed a bunch of files, “Running dpkg”, and rebooted.  I went back to the boot console in time to see the following messages repeated over and over:

```
stdin: Not a typewriter
/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sr1: No medium found
/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sr1: No medium found
```

After several minutes this finally ended at:

```
Unable to find a medium container a live file system
Attempt interactive netbood from a URL?
yes no (default yes):
```

I entered “no”, and it told me:

```
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.10.1-4ubuntu6.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

The virtual disk had grown by another couple of GB.

So … how am I supposed to “Try Ubuntu without installing”?

Comment: There is either something wrong with your VMware settings or your ISO is corrupted.  Did you verify the checksum hash?  Or perhaps you're missing something when you walk away from your device.  I suggest that you make an effort to stay by your PC while you boot up the container for the first time. Are you really using a physical DVD?

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu has two different products, *yy.mm* releases such as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for desktops & servers, and Ubuntu Core 20 (a *yy* only product) for IoT appliances, devices & cloud use. Ubuntu 20 implies a different system to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  Do you have released media? (and not old *dailies*)  That error occurred for about a month during the development cycle, but will only occur on released media with flawed media (either ISO was invalid; https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) or write to media was faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind — I stumbled on the cause of the problem, and it was VMware. ‍♂️

When I went into the VM settings to delete the virtual disk, I found that unbeknownst to me VMware had *inserted* another virtual CD drive using an image named “autoinst.iso”, as well as a virtual floppy using the image “autoinst.flp”.  I had *explicitly* created the machine without a floppy.  So I removed both autoinst drives, deleted and re-created the virtual disk, and booted again, and this time it finally came up with the “Welcome” screen and asked me to choose whether to “Try Ubuntu” or “Install Ubuntu”.